# Is it possible to make the East Siberian mountains tall enough in order for the Okhotsk coast, the Amur region and Kamchatka fertile?

Tags: climate, geography

A follow-up of another question I posted, I just learned seconds after posting that my question does not have to be answered. My most important question: in relation to the Siberian high entering the Okhotsk sea and Northeastern Siberia east of the Verkhoyansk mountains, I am asking if a tall enough range could block most of the cold, dry air from entering Manchuria and the Okhotsk coast as well as Kamchatka. According to what I have seen, I could imagine a continental climate and hope that other currents won't make the region too cold for significant agriculture.

Comment: Kamtchatka is a relatively cold place, but not excessively cold; but it has *a lot* of precipitation, about three times as much as the notoriously rainy England. The moisture most definitely does not come from Siberia. Due to the very high amount of precipitation, it is covered by snow for half of the year. Considering only temperature, the south-eastern part of the peninsula, around [Petropavlovsk Kamchatsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petropavlovsk-Kamchatsky), has a mild climate, with summer maxima of 17 °C (63 °F) and winter minima of −9 °C (16 °F), not so very different from Warsaw.

Comment: I might not understand what you're asking. Where there are mountains, there is always a rationale to make them taller in an imaginary world. If there wasn't such a rationale, there wouldn't be mountains in the first place. What problem are you trying to solve? What's stopping you from declaring the mountains taller in your alternate-earth?

Comment: It's that I don't know whether making these mountains will solve the fact that the Okhotsk coast and Kamchatka are too cold. That's what I'm trying to solve. @JBH

Comment: The cold air from Siberia is only one factor. The Oyashio Current is a big contributor as well (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oyashio_Current). If you're willing to create mountains, creating some in the ocean to block it would make the climate warmer as well.

Comment: Where would be the best place to build such mountains? maybe a small land bridge with a tall mountain range running across Chukotka and Alaska? @Matthias

Comment: @Matthias That was a good start to a good answer!

Answer (score 1):

If we take a look at the region,

[image]

Edited from: http://www.coastalwiki.org/wiki/Ocean_circulation

There are two reasons, why this region is so cold:

You already mentioned the wind from Siberia, this is caused by the trade winds (westerlies, black arrows in the left) the same winds that bring moist warm air to Europe. These winds are not as strong on land, but it is still the prevalent direction. I am not sure, how tall these mountains need to be to block these winds. Looking at other mountains that divide climate zones, I would guess it would be a minimum of 2000-3000 meters. Even if the winds can pass over the mountains, they would be much warmer afterwards due to the Foehn effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foehn_wind).

Especially Kamchatka is also strongly affected by the Oyashio current coming from the Arctic. A barrier in the sea (red line in the right) would block this current. It is enough if the "mountains" here are slightly below the water surface. This could be visible as an island chain. When the Oyashio current is blocked, the Kuroshio current could go further north, warming the Kamchatka peninsula and the Sea of Okhotsk. If this happens, high pressure zones would form over the warm ocean, leading to winds from the ocean to the land, leading to a warmer oceanic climate in this region, not unlike the climate in Europe. Of course, the Kuroshio current is not the gulf stream and the resulting winds would go against the trade winds (in contrast to Europe) so this effect would not be as strong as in Europe.

Obviously, all of this is speculative, especially the part about the Kuroshio current.

Comment: Cool so it's possible, but how feasible is it to build such mountains? Would the cost for an economically developed country encompassing North Asia make such a process possible? @Matthias

Comment: @Bangerblade I would say it is not impossible. In the end, It's just moving earth and stone from one place to another, only the dimensions are extreme. I would guess a rich country (with an economical comparable to the USA) might be able to do it in some decades if they devote all their economical resources to it. But the cost-benefit ratio is just awful, it would probably make more sense to build a lot of greenhouses in the region. I did'nt know you wanted to build it, I thought we were looking at an alternative geological scenario.

Comment: Would the Greenhouse effect influence the global climate?

Comment: Definitely, are you planning to add Climate Change as well?

Comment: Actually no. In this timeline, climate change has been reversed to preindustrial levels.

Comment: Then there is only the natural Greenhouse effect. I am not sure whether there has been a misunderstanding. When I wrote that it is easier to build a lot of greenhouses, I meant literal greenhouses.

Comment: I am still bothered by one question, if the Oyashio current is blocked instead of the Siberian high, how much of Siberia will be warmed up? Just the coasts from Vladivostok up to Kamchatka or will the interior such as places like Oymyakon or Yakutsk will endure the same warming? I noticed that you said that land trade winds such as those causing the Siberian cold are not as strong as those from the Ocean... Is there any likely hypothesis in the extent? Such as the Okhotsk mountains being short enough to let the warm oceanic air pass by?